# Is there encryption on redirects to https from http

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, encryption, https

I have a server and every page has a redirect to use the SSL (https) using htacess. My question is what if someone types in the url http://www.domain.com/ and it redirects to https://www.domain.com was the information sent in the original request un-encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

> was the information sent in the original request un-encrypted?

Yes, the `http://domain.com/` request is unencrypted, as is the response that contains the redirect. The SSL handshake happens before any data is sent, and until the browser knows to initiate an SSL handshake on the SSL port, everything is unencrypted.

Comment: So if someone tries to send, lets say username and password, to http://www.domain.com anyone could potentially intercept that request and get the username and password? even if there is a redirect or SSLRequireSSL?

Answer (score 2):

Jon Lin's answer is correct.  If this is a security concern, then it's best to ensure that the user *only* connects to your site by way of https, or redirecting from their first connection, before any sensitive information is sent.  This can be done using the .htaccess file.

Comment: This can't be done via redirection rules in `.htaccess` precisely because of the reasons given in Jon Lin's answer.

Comment: If you add `SSLRequireSSL` to the .htaccess file, it will prevent the user's browser from connecting by http and will only allow https connections.

Comment: The initial request will still be sent over plain HTTP (possibly including the request entity, depending on the client configuration). It's only once the initial request is received that `SSLRequireSSL` can take effect (in processing that request and sending the response). It all depends on whether there's sensitive data in this initial requests, of course, but only the client can really enforce usage of HTTPS.

Comment: True, there are scenarios where sensitive data could be sent in the initial http request.  It's hard to imagine how this would happen in a browser based application (because the browser would have to send the information without the user being prompted for it first).  But, it could happen if the web server is being used to host a web services API or something of that nature.  Probably the best solution in this case to simply disable incoming http connections on the web server (or block port 80 on the firewall), so that clients cannot even make a http connections.

Comment: This problem can also happen is the application on the server posts a form to an absolute `http://` URL for example. Disabling port 80 doesn't help against MITM attacks either. Knowing you want `https` and not ignoring warning are the only things that can really help, as well as HSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the information passed via `http` protocol remains unencrypted. All the communication via http will be then unencrypted. Redirection occours after transmission of packet to the redirecting server so this communication can not be encrypted just by redirecting to https site.